# How to change the source of big image after clicking on the small image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a set of small images stacked on the side and a larger version of the image on the right. I want the large image to change when I click on the small image but the problem is I could achieve this using vanilla JavaScript but I am unable to do that in reactjs.

Screenshot of how it looks is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nirGj.png)

And below is the code

```
<div class="header-body">

        <div class="wrapper">

          <div class="product-box">

            <div class="all-images">

            <div class="small-images">

              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5LdMxNp/image.jpg" alt="image" onclick="clickimg(this)">

              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TqMj09C/image-1.jpg" alt="image" onclick="clickimg(this)">

              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5LdMxNp/image.jpg" alt="image" onclick="clickimg(this)">

              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5LdMxNp/image.jpg" alt="image" onclick="clickimg(this)">

        </div>

            <div class="main-images">

              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5LdMxNp/image.jpg" id="imagebox">

            </div>

            </div>

      </div>
```

And below is the vanilla JavaScript function I wrote

```
function clickimg(smallImg){

  var fullImg = document.getElementById("imagebox");

  fullImg.src= smallImg.src;

}
```

This runs properly on codepen. But this function doesn't work in reactjs.

Comment: any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You should have use storage for an active image or as you said "main";

if you use React with hooks `useState` will good match to you to store active image;

And you should add function that handles clicking on small image;

```
<div class="small-images">
   <img src='1' onClick={handleClick}/>
   <img src='2' onClick={handleClick}/>
   <img src='3' onClick={handleClick}/>
</div

<div class="big-image">
   <img src={activeImage || '*src to default image*'}/>
</div>
```

```
const [activeImage, setActiveImage] = useState(*first or whatever logic*)

function handleClick(event){
   console.dir(event.target) // you should better inspect your HTML element
   const src = event.target.src;
   setActiveImage(src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the component state to keep track of the URL of the clicked small image, then set the currentImage as the `src` of the big image. See sample code below:

```
import React from "react";

export const ImageViewer = () => {
  const [currentImageURL, setcurrentImageURL] = useState("");

  //   Array of product image urls, *can be an object data structure for extra properties*
  const productImageURLs = [
    "https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=1",
    "https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=2",
    "https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=3",
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Small images */}
      {productImageURLs.map((url) => {
        return (
          <img
            src={url}
            className='small image'
            alt='small preview of product'
            onClick={() => setcurrentImageURL(url)}
          />
        );
      })}

      {/* Big image */}
      <img
        src={currentImageURL || productImageURLs[0]}
        className='big-img'
        alt='large preview of product'
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This works fine, but when the page loads the big image is empty. How should I add a default image in it?

Comment: Add a default image i.e `productImageURLs[0]`, I've updated my answer as well.